# Open source CMS in stripes?

Tags: java, content-management-system, open-source, stripes

Is there any existing open source CMS in stripes?

I'm especially looking for a very tiny and lightweight one that I can take a look at and learn from.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I've been unable to find a lightweight CMS in *any* language.

Java has the JSR 170 Java Content Repository specification, with Jackrabbit being the reference impelementation. Unfortunately, my experience has been that it is neither lightweight nor easy to learn from.

You might try looking at some of the version control systems and filesystems though: their functionality is overlapping and may resemble yours.

Comment: JCR170 seems like a very inconvenient and inelligent way to store data for a CMS.

Comment: I think elegance is relative, and depends on what you want from a CMS.  You can store relationships between objects and attributes in tree, direct acyclic graph, full graph, and other data models.  Each has different implications for usability and performance, depending on what kind of info you want to store.  Personally, I wasn't impressed with JCR either. It seemed like a standard and a framework hunting for an application, rather than the other way around.  That opinion might change if I saw a killer app using it.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to http://wiki.opensymphony.com/display/ABLE/Home, it use Stripes and other tools. 
Is not a pure CMS but a framework for building CRUD applications and auto-generating controllers and scaffolding.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you really have to learn something a little more modern. Stripes is just a better Struts which isnt much. Both are dated and do next to nothing in terms of building something snazzy.